# Vimeo API - Getting video's direct link by quality (C#)

Tags: json, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a single-user application,

in Vimeo's playground, when doing video/{id}, i get a big JSON result that contains:

```
"files": [
        {
            "quality": "hd",
            "type": "video/mp4",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "link": "...link...",
            "created_time": "2018-02-15T13:46:25+00:00",
            "fps": 23.980000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875,
            "size": 3113207678,
            "md5": "b6beed65b699df870e481045178accc5",
            "link_secure": "...link..."
        },
        {
            "quality": "sd",
            "type": "video/mp4",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 360,
            "link": "...link...",
            "created_time": "2018-02-15T13:46:05+00:00",
            "fps": 23.980000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875,
            "size": 536864946,
            "md5": "af227a5526af15d2bce6ac951d6cf06b",
            "link_secure": "...link..."
        },
        {
            "quality": "sd",
            "type": "video/mp4",
            "width": 960,
            "height": 540,
            "link": "...link...",
            "created_time": "2018-02-15T13:46:05+00:00",
            "fps": 23.980000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875,
            "size": 1242328160,
            "md5": "1963f908509b14fd7a40dc46bfa6c519",
            "link_secure": "...link..."
        },
        {
            "quality": "hd",
            "type": "video/mp4",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720,
            "link": "...link...",
            "created_time": "2018-02-15T13:46:05+00:00",
            "fps": 23.980000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875,
            "size": 1977386604,
            "md5": "af38f067bd39f4f5bb71bad72f925337",
            "link_secure": "...link..."
        },
        {
            "quality": "hls",
            "type": "video/mp4",
            "link": "...link...",
            "created_time": "2018-02-15T13:46:25+00:00",
            "fps": 23.980000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875,
            "size": 3113207678,
            "md5": "b6beed65b699df870e481045178accc5",
            "link_secure": "...link..."
        }
```

(i edited the urls out)

but when doing the same call in my code, the whole "files" section is missing (also the whole json result looks different):

[image: json]

this is my code, the call:

```
vc.Request("/videos/255898412", null, "GET");
```

request method:

```
 public Dictionary<string, object> Request(
            string url,
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters,
            string method,
            bool jsonBody = true)
        { 
            var headers = new WebHeaderCollection()
            {
                { "Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", AccessToken) }
            };
            method = method.ToUpper();
            url = apiRoot + url;
            string body = "";
            string contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
            {
                if (method == "GET")
                {
                    url += "?" + Helpers.KeyValueToString(parameters);
                }
                else if (method == "POST" || method == "PATCH" || method == "PUT" || method == "DELETE")
                {
                    if (jsonBody)
                    {
                        contentType = "application/json";
                        body = jsonEncode(parameters);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        body = Helpers.KeyValueToString(parameters);
                    }
                }
            }


            return  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(Helpers.HTTPFetch(url, method, headers, body, contentType));

        }
```

My goal is to get the HLS direct link, to play it in my player .
How can i achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem today.

My stupid solution is as follows.

- Use 3.1 version of API

Comment: @AaYy This was a bug in API v3.4 that has since been resolved. Make your request again with 3.4 and if you're still having any trouble, contact Vimeo - https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: @AaYy Odd. Can you email Vimeo and reference this StackOverflow thread, and reply back here with your support ticket reference number? Would love to figure this one out. Thanks! -- https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: @TommyPenner Actually i already did it yesterday, didn't saved the ticket number

Comment: @TommyPenner I'm still experiencing this problem with 3.4, even if using a token with video_files. Ticket number #3552635.

Comment: @franzo I just replied to your support email. For anyone else who finds this answer/comment, make sure your API app defaults to v3.4 as shown on the app management page. If you're using an older version, or your app defaults to an older version, create a new API app on the Vimeo Developer Site, which will default to v3.4.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug where the download and files keys were not returning for devs using API v3.4. Vimeo has since fixed the bug (as of 2/23/2018).

Starting with API v3.4, developers must authenticate requests using a token with the `video_files` scope to receive the download and files keys in the video response.

If you're generating tokens using the OAuth workflow, you can generate a token with the video_files scope that way: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#supported-scopes

I hope this information helps!